# UserWarning: pyarrow.open_stream is deprecated, please use pyarrow.ipc.open_stream warnings

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, user-defined-functions, pyarrow

I am running `spark 2.4.2` locally through `pyspark` for an ML project in NLP. Part of the pre-processing steps in the Pipeline involve the use of `pandas_udf` functions optimized through `pyarrow`. Each time I operate with the pre-processed spark dataframe the following warning appears:

> UserWarning: pyarrow.open_stream is deprecated, please use pyarrow.ipc.open_stream
>     warnings.warn("pyarrow.open_stream is deprecated, please use "

I tried updating `pyarrow` but didn't manage to avoid the warning. My pyarrow version is 0.14. I was wondering the implications of this warning and if somebody has found a solution for it? Thank you very much in advance.

Spark session details:

```
conf = SparkConf(). \
setAppName('map'). \
setMaster('local[*]'). \
set('spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.PYSPARK_PYTHON', '~/anaconda3/bin/python'). \
set('spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON', '~/anaconda3/bin/python'). \
set('executor.memory', '8g'). \
set('spark.executor.memoryOverhead', '16g'). \
set('spark.sql.codegen', 'true'). \
set('spark.yarn.executor.memory', '16g'). \
set('yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb', '500m'). \
set('spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors', '3'). \
set('spark.driver.maxResultSize', '0'). \
set("spark.sql.execution.arrow.enabled", "true"). \
set("spark.debug.maxToStringFields", '100')

spark = SparkSession.builder. \
    appName("map"). \
    config(conf=conf). \
    getOrCreate()
```

Comment: I finally fixed the warning in pycharm by downgrading pyarrow from 0.14 to 0.11. So, under the project interpreter in your environment run in terminal:

    `pip uninstall pyarrow`
and 
    `pip install pyarrow==0.11`

When running from terminal (or jupyter) the warning does not appear, so this solution can be helpful for those willing to work with pyarrow in pycharm

Comment: If you're getting this warning in Databricks, you may want to upgrade to 6.2: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-29875

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This warning is coming from your version of `pyspark`, which is using a deprecated function of `pyarrow`.

But everything works fine, so you can either simply ignore the warning for now, or update your pyspark version (in the latest version they have fixed the usage of the deprecated pyarrow function)

Answer (score 0):

I've the same problem in `pycharm`, when using `jupyter lab` it seems to be working fine