# Fastest way to apply multiple regular expressions sequentially for text cleaning in Pyspark

Tags: python, regex, apache-spark, databricks

I have a column that I wish to clean using a whole lot of regular expressions that I want to apply sequentially.

Even pandas it is the time consuming process but at least I can get away by applying it as a function.

As a concrete example:

```
import pandas as pd
import re


regex_tuples_list = [(r'\bMR\b', 'middle right', re.I), 
                     ('\bmiddle right area\b', 'center', re.I),
                    ]

def apply_regex(text):
    for (to_repl, value, re_flags) in regex_tuples_list:
        to_repl_compiled = re.compile(to_repl, re_flags)
        text = re.sub(to_repl_compiled, value, text)
    return text

s = pd.Series(['Install the part in the MR', 
               'Check the MR area before using the tool', 
               'Always begin from the middle right area',
              ])

print(s.apply(apply_regex))

## Prints...
#      Install the part in the middle right
#    Check the center before using the tool
#              Always begin from the center
```

What would be the best way to do it using Pyspark?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your code with `pandas` can directly run on databricks without any other operation, as the figure below.

[image]

Then, I see you want to get the better performance for doing the same thing, so I think you can try to use the [`koalas`](https://koalas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) package for PySpark to get the similar UX like `pandas`. And to install `koalas` package in the cluster of databricks is very easy, just follow the figure below to install it.

[image]

Note: the latest version of `koalas` package requires `spark-2.4.4`, so you must have to select Spark `2.4.4` version for creating the cluster as the figure below.

[image]

Finally, you just need to use `import databricks.koalas as ks` instead of `import pandas as pd` without any more code changes to run your same code with PySpark for better performance, as the figure below.

[image]

Don't worry about the user warning information for calling deprecated function, you can refer to the SO thread [UserWarning: pyarrow.open_stream is deprecated, please use pyarrow.ipc.open_stream warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57028570/userwarning-pyarrow-open-stream-is-deprecated-please-use-pyarrow-ipc-open-stre) to know about it.